# Got undefined when accessing variables that are initialized outside of subscribe

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm working with Apex chart and the chart is in the second component. I need to call a function to toggle some series in second component from the first component. I'm able to call that function now but when I try to call the chart inside the subscribe, it's undefined. However if I call that chart in the ngAfterViewInit(), the chart is correct. So could anyone suggest me any ideas to access the chart inside the subscribe?

Second component:

```js
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild("chart") chart!: ChartComponent;
  constructor(public servic: MainService, private spinner: NgxSpinnerService, private router: Router) {
    this.servic.receiveMessage().subscribe(message => {
      this.toggle(message)
    })
  }
  public toggle(state: string) {
    console.log(this.chart);

  }
}
```

HTML of the second component:
[image: Image for the second component]

Answer (score 0):

It is not `undefined` because it is inside `.subscribe()`. It is `undefined` because it is inside the `constructor()`. This is a run time issue. Move your subscription to `OnInit()` or `AfterViewInit()` [lifecycle hooks](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks)

Comment: If I put that in OnInit or AfterViewInit, the subscribe won't work when I try to call the function from first component

Answer (score 0):

your service file is getting called later that's why your "message" uder subscribe is undefined, move your service into OnInit() from constructor()..

```
constructor(public servic: MainService, private spinner: NgxSpinnerService, private router: Router) {}
    ngOnInit(){
    this.servic.receiveMessage().subscribe(message => {
          this.toggle(message)
        })
    }
public toggle(state: string) {
    console.log(this.chart);

  }
```

Comment: I tried to put that in ngOnInit but toggle is not called when I call the function from the first component

Comment: could you please paste here HTML & ts file here (only required code)